Target undefined solution please
My problem is that after writing this code:
const form = document.getElementById('form'); 



function handleSubmit(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); 

}



const data = {}; 

const fields = event.target.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea'); 

for (const field of fields) {

  data[field.name] = field.value;

} 

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit); 

It shows this type error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')https://fc349b7a-5180-4c97-9432-82f7df6d86fe-00-b9jrwad18xpf.pike.replit.dev/script.js:8
I was trying to do a form validation course from frontend mentor and this happened

Which lines do you need in handleSubmit? This has to be in const fields = event.target.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');.

Have a look at What is the scope of variables in JavaScript? - You most likely meant to put that code the uses event inside of your function, otherwise, you'll most likely be accessing window.event which would give you the error you're seeing.

It seems like the Braces ( curly brackets ) for the function are misplaced
const form = document.getElementById('form');

function handleSubmit(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  // instead of closing the function here 

  const data = {};

  const fields = event.target.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');

  for (const field of fields) {
    data[field.name] = field.value
  }

} // should be here wrapping it all up

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

edit: From @Andy answer below me
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

to this:
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => handleSubmit(e));


I just tidied up your code to better show the indentation. FWIW form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit(e)); is wrong. form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => handleSubmit(e)); would be correct but slightly pointless.
